# shell script - complete iteration before exiting infinite loop

Tags: shell, infinite-loop

I am very new to shell scripting and need help in this.

I would like to run some commands with infinite loop and I want the loop to be terminated on ctrl-c is pressed, but before terminate I want current iteration to be completed (means all the statements within the loop should be executed.

```
infinite-loop (
   command 1;
   command 2; 
   command 3;
loop-ends
```

so on ctrl-c at any point in execution, all 3 commands should be executed before the loops is terminated. loops should continue to execute if ctrl-c is not pressed.

any suggestion please??

Answer (score 3):

You can use `trap` to trap the SIGINT signal. (tested)

```
#!/bin/sh

trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c () {
  RUNNING=0
}

RUNNING=1

while [  "$RUNNING" = 1 ]; do
  echo 'working'
  sleep 1
  echo 'on something else'
  sleep 1
  echo 'done'
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this (untested)

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "DONE=1" SIGINT
DONE=0
while [ $DONE -eq 0 ]
do
    process1
    process2
    process3
done
```